# Let $T(f)(y)=\int_0^\infty K(x,y)\cdot f(x)dx$, $\,$ show $\,$ $\Vert T(f) \Vert _p \le C\cdot \Vert f \Vert _p$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, holder-inequality

Now here is the full statement.

> Let $K:(0, +\infty) \times (0, +\infty) \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a Lebesgue measurable function with $K(kx,ky)=k^{-1}K(x,y)$ for every $k>0$ and let
>   $$\int_0^\infty |K(x,1)|\cdot x^{-\frac 1p}\,dx=C<\infty$$
>   For some $p\in[1,\infty]$. If $f\in L^p$ show that the function
>   $$T(f)(y)=\int_0^\infty K(x,y)\cdot f(x)\,dx$$
>   is well defined for almost every $y\in (0,+\infty)$ and satisfies $\Vert T(f) \Vert _p \leq C \Vert f \Vert _p$.

I've been using inequalities for hours and got nowhere. I tried using Hölder's inequality and Tonelli's Theorem in many ways and got frustrated everytime. Any idea would help me a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe we have
\begin{align}
\|T(f)\|_p =& \left(\int^\infty_0 \left|\int^\infty_0 K(x, y)f(x)\ dx \right|^p\ dy\right)^{1/p}\\
=&\ \left(\int^\infty_0 \left|\int^\infty_0 K(u, 1)f(yu)\ du \right|^p\ dy\right)^{1/p}.
\end{align}
Then by Minkowski's integral inequality (essentially triangle inequality), we have
\begin{align}
\|T(f)\|_p \leq&\ \int^\infty_0 |K(u, 1)|\left( \int^\infty_0 |f(yu)|^p dy\right)^{1/p}\ du\\
=&\ \int^\infty_0|K(u, 1)|u^{-1/p}\left(\int^\infty_0 |f(x)|^p\ dx \right)^{1/p}\ du.
\end{align}

**Edit:** If $p \in [1, \infty)$, then we know that $C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$. 
Since the above estimate holds on $C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})$ then it extends uniquely
to all of $L^p(\mathbb{R})$. Since $T(f) \in L^p$ then we know that the set of $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $T(f)(y)=\infty$ is measure zero.

In the case $p=\infty$, we see that
\begin{align}
|T(f)(y)| =&\  \left|\int^\infty_0 K(u, 1) f(yu)\ du\right|\\
\leq &\ \int^\infty_0 |K(u, 1)|\ du\cdot \|f\|_{L^\infty}.
\end{align}
Hence $T$ is well-defined for all $f \in L^\infty$.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty clever. I don't wont to push to hard but have you thought about the "well defined" part? Im struggling with that too, the "almost everywhere" part leaves me clueless. Even if you don't, I'm very grateful for your elegant+simple answer