# Show that the mapping $(Tf)(x) = \frac{1}{x}\int_0^{\infty}K(\frac{y}{x})f(y)dy$ is bounded

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $K$ be a Lebesgue measurable function defined on $(0, \infty)$ and assume $\int_0^{\infty}\vert\,K(y)\,\vert y^{-\frac{1}{p}}dy < \infty$. Pick $f \in L_p(0, \infty) (p > 1)$ and define a linear mapping $T$ by:
$$(Tf)(x) = \int_0^{\infty}K(y)f(x y) dy = \frac{1}{x}\int_0^{\infty}K(\frac{y}{x})f(y)dy, x > 0$$

My questions are:

1. $\forall\,f \in L_p(0, \infty), Tf \in L_p(0, \infty)$ **(solved)**
2. $\|\,T\| \leq \int_0^{\infty}\vert\,K(y)\,\vert y^{-\frac{1}{p}}dy$ **(solved)** and the equality holds when $K$ is non-negative **(not solved)**

To prove the first two, by using Minkowski's integral inequality and replace $y$ by $t x$, I tried:
$$[\int_0^{\infty}\vert\,\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}K(t)f(t x)d t\,\vert^p dx]^{\frac{1}{p}} \leq \int_0^{\infty}[\int_0^{\infty}\vert\,\frac{1}{x}K(t)f(t x)\,\vert^p dx]^{\frac{1}{p}} dt = \\\int_0^{\infty}\vert\,K(t)\,\vert[\int_0^{\infty}\vert\,\frac{t}{x}f(x)\,\vert^p\frac{1}{t}dx]^{\frac{1}{p}} d t = \int_0^{\infty}\vert\,K(t)\,\vert t^{-\frac{1}{p}}\underline{[\int_0^{\infty}\vert\,\frac{t}{x}f(x)\,\vert^p dx]^{\frac{1}{p}}} d t$$

Then I can not compare the underlined part and $\|f\|_p$. If my attempt is on the right track, could you anyone provide hints on how to do the desired comparison? Also I was block by the second part of question 2 and the third question. I am not sure if I can apply Minkowski's inequality when $K$ is not absolutely integrable. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3039023/) is a similar question but I could not find it helpful ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the assumption on $K$ should be that $$\int^\infty_0 |K(y)|\,y^{-1/p}\,dy<\infty$$
As you pointed out, the generalized Minkowski inequality gives
\begin{align}
\left(\int^\infty_0\left|\int^\infty_0 K(y) f(xy)\,dy\right|^p\,dx\right)^{1/p} &\leq \left(\int^\infty_0\left(\int^\infty_0 |K(y)| |f(xy)|\,dy\right)^p\,dx\right)^{1/p}\\
&\leq\int^\infty_0\left(\int^\infty_0 |f(xy)|^p\,dx\right)^{1/p}|K(y)|\,dy\\
&=\|f\|_p\int^\infty_0y^{-1/p}|K(y)|\,dy
\end{align}

---

This is the version of the general Minkowski inequality that I am using:

Suppose $f:(X\times Y,\mathscr{F}\otimes\mathscr{G})\rightarrow(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ is measureable and that where $(X,\mathscr{F},\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathscr{G},\nu)$ are $\sigma$--finite measures. Then,
\begin{align}
\Big(\int_X\Big|\int_Y f(x,y)\,
\nu(dy)\Big|^p\,\mu(dx)\Big)^{\tfrac{1}{p}}\leq
 \int_Y \Big(\int_X |f(x,y)|^p\,\mu(dx)\Big)^{\tfrac{1}{p}}\,\nu(dy)
\end{align}
for all $1\leq p<\infty$.

---

Comments:

1. Your problem is a particular case of the problem you [quoted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3039023/let-tfy-int-0-infty-kx-y-cdot-fxdx-show-vert-tf-vert). Indeed, notice that
   $$k(x,y):=\frac{1}{y}K(x/y)$$
   is homogeneous of order $-1$, that
   $$\int^\infty_0k(x,1) x^{-1/p}\,dx = \int^\infty_0K(x) x^{-1/p}\,dx,$$ and that
   $$ Tf(y)=\int^\infty_0k(x,y)f(x)\,dx$$
2. Thus far we have proved that
   $$\|T\|\leq\int^\infty_0|K(x)|x^{-1/p}\,dx$$
   regardless of the sign of $K$.
3. The equality is not straight forward, even in the case $K\geq0$. Consider the particular case
   $$ K(x)=\mathbb{1}_{(0,1]}(x)$$
   which gives the Hardy operator
   $$Hf(y)=\frac{1}{y}\int^y_0f(x)\,dx$$
   Proving that $\|H\|=\frac{p}{p-1}=\int^1_0x^{-1/p}\,dx$ is not trivial. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3020458/121671) is a solution for this particular case

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Apparently I do not need to do the replacement of variable at the first place and need to add your condition. By the way, do you have any ideas how to show the equality holds when $K$ is non-negative?

Comment: @SanaeKochiya: I don't think that proving equality for the bound of the norm of $\|T\|$ is trivial, even in the case where $K>0$. If you have a proof for this particular case, please share it. See the comments I added to the "partial" solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your shares. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384546 is another example and also an exercises following the one I posted where $K(y) = \frac{1}{1+y}$. In the attached link $p = 2$ but in the textbook I am using the operator $T$ defined this $K(y)$ has norm $\frac{\pi}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{p})}$.

Comment: I may need to find a nice sequence of $f_n \in L^p(0, \infty)$ to help $\|\,Tf_n\,\|$ approach the norm of $T$, although it seems impossible without knowing what $K$ is ... it is like more than a non-trivial problem